# Simple Php Error Eludes Me

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm just trying to echo this text with the category title automatically pulled inside the text on wordpress. How do I do this ? I thought that the code below would work but I get php error and blank page when I implement this as a shortcode.

```
function get_quote($atts) {
echo    '<div id="le_quote">'<?php single_cat_title( $prefix = '', $display = true ); ?>' is your online supplier of Apache Accessories, Apache Hoses and Apache Pumps.  Use our selection to compare Apache models , specs and more. Buy Apache products at the best price possible today.</div>';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

Comment: *What* error are you getting exactly?

Comment: the PHP syntax is incorrect.

Comment: A blank page, if I remove `'<?php single_cat_title( $prefix = '', $display = true ); ?>'` the shortcode pulls the string fine. Something is wrong with this code

Comment: Shivan Please Explain

Answer (score 3):

Try this, Remove `<?php` and  `?>` tag from `<?php single_cat_title( $prefix = '', $display = true ); ?>` and pass `$prefix` and `$display` parameter values.

```
    function get_quote($atts) {
        echo    '<div id="le_quote">'.single_cat_title( '', false ).' is your online supplier of Apache Accessories, Apache Hoses and Apache Pumps.  Use our selection to compare Apache models , specs and more. Buy Apache products at the best price possible today.</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

Ref:

```
$display:  (boolean) (optional) Should the page title be displayed (true) or returned for use in PHP (false).  
Default: true
```

URL: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title

Comment: Yea that pulled the cat name, but its outside the div and on a separate line breaking the paragraph ...

Comment: You can use `single_cat_title( '', false )`

Answer (score 0):

you have `<?php` and `?>` inside your echo, replace that with a . and int will work:

```
 function get_quote($atts) {
    echo    '<div id="le_quote">' . single_cat_title( '', true ) . ' is your online supplier of Apache Accessories, Apache Hoses and Apache Pumps.  Use our selection to compare Apache models , specs and more. Buy Apache products at the best price possible today.</div>';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

Comment: How come when I do this the category is pulled fine but its outside the div and on a seperate line ? (http://www.aquapumps.org/product-category/brand/be-pumps/)

Comment: i'm not sure, but try changing true to false in the single_cat_title(). i believe thats for use in php instead of display

Answer (score 0):

Save the cat title to a variable then echo that.

```
function get_quote($atts) {
$cat_title = single_cat_title( '', false );
echo    '<div id="le_quote">AquaPumps.Org is your online supplier of '.$cat_title.'     
Accessories, '.$cat_title.' Hoses and '.$single_cat_title.' Pumps.  Use our selection 
to compare '.cat_title( '', true ).' models , specs and more. Buy '.cat_title.' 
products at the best price possible today.</div>';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```